# Can't import flask because werkzeug

Tags: python, flask, import, werkzeug

When I use `from flask import *`, I get the error

> ImportError: No module named werkzeug.exceptions

However, when I do `pip freeze`, I can see that `Werkzeug==0.11.11` is indeed installed.  How can I fix this?

Comment: @idjaw, chaning my code so that it does `import werkzeug` first results in `ImportError: No module named werkzeug`.  Again, this is very confounding as pip thinks it's installed.  Thank you again.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right with your environment. I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv? If you are using `sudo` you will be escaping the virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I am asumming, that the wrong version of Werkzeug was installed in the fist place. This usually happens, when you have 2 versions of python installed, and you use 'pip' for installing dependancies rather than using 'pip3'. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with Yocto while installing python-flask from: http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-virtualization.

The solution was to manually add python-werkzeug to my yocto image as well. I suspect that python-flask should depend upon python-werkzeug. Additionally, I had to add python-jinja2 as well to the image.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. 
I got this error when working in python virtual environment. 
I had to deactivate virtual environment. Then go to root user and install werkzeug using pip. After that it works in virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed quite a few flask packages only with `pip`, but that was not enough, I also got the error `ImportError: No module named werkzeug.exceptions`.

The hint of [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47783287/11154841), mentioning `python-flask` and `python-werkzeug`, brought the main idea. In my case, the solution was to `apt-get install python-flask`. It installed werkzeug as a dependency and the error was gone.